# program finishes after exception is handled in Java

Tags: java, exception

This is for homework.

I am trying to create a program that takes the average of ten input numbers. When the user enters a character that is not a number, the NumberFormatException exception is caught. The program was finishing after the exception was caught, so I changed it to use recursion to call the method again after the exception is caught, but now it prints multiple averages, some of which are not correct.

How do I change the program so that it continues to ask for input after an exception has been caught instead of finishing? I do not want the program to finish after catching the exception.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrintAverage {

    int average;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("You are going to enter ten numbers to find their average.");
        getInput();
    }

    private static void getInput() {
        String input;
        int sum = 0;
        int[] arrayOfIntegers = new int[10];
        double average = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfIntegers.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter the next number.");
                input = scanner.nextLine();
                arrayOfIntegers[i] = Integer.parseInt(input);
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
            System.out.println("The last entry was not a valid number.");
            getInput();
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < arrayOfIntegers.length; k++) {
            sum = sum + arrayOfIntegers[k];
        }
        average = sum / arrayOfIntegers.length;
        System.out.println("The average is " + average);

    }
}
```

Comment: You might consider using `Scanner.hasNextInt()` to validate that the input is an integer before trying to parse it (using `Scanner.nextInt()`).

Comment: Nice one! Here's the doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt--

Comment: `getInput()` method should only do what its name says: Get The Input. Please move the average calculation in another method, and call it when the array of integers is ready.

Comment: I agree. It's often better to have methods with return values. It helps making them reusable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your try/catch is not specific enough, so it catches the exception after asking all the numbers you want.

1. Identify the line that is throwing the NumberFormatException
2. Move your try/catch around it
3. Store the input in a temporary variable that can be null (primitive int don't allow that)
4. Keep asking for a value as long as it's null (= as long as it's not been set to a legit number)

Comment: Nice answer that describes the general principles of a solution and yet allows the OP to figure out the coding for them-self. 1+

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks :-) I believe homework questions/answers have little value here if we just post code that works.

Comment: 1. NumberFormatException should be thrown by parseInt. | 2. If I take the other stuff out of the try block then it will just be the parseInt line. | 3. I have not figured out this part yet. | 4. I will have to figure this out too. Thank you very much.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. That's fine. When you'll read your code later you will see easily what you're trying to catch because the try/catch will surround only 1 line. 3. `Integer` allows null values (it's an `Object`), but `int` don't (they are primitives types). You could keep using an `int` and initializing it to `-1` but when the user would type `-1` the code would ignore this value. So I prefer using `null` here.

Answer (score 1):

Localize the exception.
Change this:

```
try {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfIntegers.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the next number.");
            input = scanner.nextLine();
            arrayOfIntegers[i] = Integer.parseInt(input);
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
        System.out.println("The last entry was not a valid number.");
        getInput();
    }
```

to this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfIntegers.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter the next number.");
        input = scanner.nextLine();
        try {
           arrayOfIntegers[i] = Integer.parseInt(input);
        } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
            System.out.println("The last entry was not a valid number.");
            i--; //so you don't lose one of the 10.
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will continue the loop, making arrayOfIntegers not entirely initialized.

Comment: I don't like messing with indexes because it makes the code less readable. I prefer something along the lines
`while(userInput == null) {
    try{
        userInput = scanner.nextLine();
    } catch(E){...}
}
doSomething(userInput);
`

which I find more easy to understand.

Comment: @pyb - that's cool.  It's fun to see how others solve things.  I don't mind messing with indexes if it's in exception handling myself.  Frankly the comment with Scanner.hasNextInt seems like the best approach.

Comment: I agree, I did not know it existed.